Trouble to setup tls with kubernetes: "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR"
I'm trying to setup tls/https for my kubernetes-pod. I configured an ingress rule and I've a got service as loadbalancer. I obtained my certificate from my provider. Not sure, how important that is: It's wildcard certificate: *.my-domain.org
(Note: my-domain.org is a replacement ;) )
The browser returns "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR".
curl returns "curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_INVALID_TOKEN (0x80090308)"
By the way: http is running successfully.
My steps in detail:
I've got a certificate and a key that I'm adding as secret:
kubectl create secret tls tls-secret -n default --cert=ssl_certificate.cer --key=private_key.key

This is the setup of my ingress rule:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - my-domain.org
    secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: my-domain.org
    http: 
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend: 
          service:
            name: my-service
            port:
              number: 80

This is my service:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: my-service
spec:
    selector:               
        app: my-pod
    ports:                  
    - protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 3000
      port: 80
      name: http
    - protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 3000      
      port: 443         
      name: https                 
    type: LoadBalancer   

And finally my pod created by the following deployment:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: my-deployment
spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            app: my-pod
    minReadySeconds: 5
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                app: my-pod
        spec:
            containers:
            - name: my-container
              image: registry.../nextapp:latest
              imagePullPolicy: Always
              stdin: true
              tty: true
              ports:
              - containerPort: 3000
                name: http
            imagePullSecrets:
            - name: registry-credentials
            restartPolicy: Always


@ xforfun  Did you have time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your issue? If not, I am happy to assist further.

@SaiChandiniRouthu Thanks for asking. I checked most points and they are fine. Unfortunately I have trouble to check all logs due to my provider. ssllabs.com returns "No secure protocols supported".

@ xforfun  which provider you are using?

1&1 IONOS Cloud in Germany.

@ xforfun Clearing your browser's cache and cookies might help and try a different browser to see if the problem persists.

@ xforfun Have you Checked your ingress rule is the hosts field in the TLS section should match the specific domain you are accessing in your browser.

@ xforfun  Sometimes an incorrect system date/time can affect SSL verification. A simple restart can fix network connectivity problems.

Host is same as in browser. I tried a different browser with cleared cache. Firefox returns "SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG". Not sure if this is helpful?!

Have  you restart?

@ xforfun  Try with this command kubectl get secret  tls-secret -n default   -o yaml to view the secrets and verify all the necessary certificates are there or not

@  xforfun Have you checked your Wildcard certificate.it should helps the domain you are used to accessing the service. Also make sure the SAN field in the certificate includes the "my-domain.org"

These errors “ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR" and schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_INVALID_TOKEN (0x80090308)" will indicates that there is an issue with the TLS configuration for your kubernetes ingress  with the wild card certificate.
Follow  this troubleshooting doc by Infinitive Host to resolve your issue

Check SSL Certificate: Ensure that your SSL certificate is installed
correctly on your server and hasn’t expired. You can use SSL checker
tools to verify the certificate status and configuration.
Double-check your server’s SSL/TLS configuration to ensure it’s
correctly set up. Make sure that the SSL/TLS protocols and cipher
suites are properly configured and up-to-date.
where some resources are loaded over HTTP instead of HTTPS, can
trigger SSL protocol errors. Make sure all resources (such as images,
scripts, and stylesheets) are served over HTTPS.
Check your server logs for any errors or warnings related to SSL/TLS
connections. Logs may provide insights into the underlying issue.
Check your ingress rule is The hosts field in the TLS section should
match the specific domain you are accessing in your browser.

NOTE:
Always remember to restart Ingress Controller along with pods after making changes in configuration.
